# Python REST API Login/Authentication/Authorization for Mobile App

Tags: android, django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, jwt, python-social-auth

I've probably spent 150 hours the past two weeks reading up and watching tutorials on mobile app security and authentication strategies for REST APIs, and I've perhaps never been more confused and overwhelmed in my life, lol. I've learned a thousand things I *shouldn't* do, but I still have no real handle on what I *should* do.

As background, this mobile app won't be dealing with super sensitive information (no financials, no HIPAA content, etc.), but I still want to secure it and its REST API with best practices, preferably while maintaining my sanity. The API will be private to the app, Python-based, and allow email/password login as well as social login (Google/Facebook). Once users initially register and log in, they should never really have to log in again unless they intentionally log out or want to log in on a second device.

I've looked into both Django Rest Framework and Flask for building the API, and even though the nuts-and-bolts style of the latter seems more to my liking, I've homed in more on DRF since it seems to have better documentation out there with respect to authentication. Among the most helpful guides I've walked through to date are this 2018 Medium article on [Guide to an OAuth2 API with Django](https://medium.com/@halfspring/guide-to-an-oauth2-api-with-django-6ba66a31d6d); and this 2020 YouTube video on [Social Logins with React and DRF](https://youtu.be/wlcCvzOLL8w) (using drf-social-oauth2).

However, I'm still left with a ton of questions/concerns:

- I've yet to find a guide/tutorial that helps me fully understand how to implement PCKE into the OAuth2 workflow (which seems to be the current recommendation). Is PCKE really standard practice these days, or have I just gone too deep down the security rabbit hole?
- With libraries like drf-social-oauth2 and django-allauth + dj-rest-auth, I'm struggling to understand how to separate the authorization server from the resource server (and perhaps a third authentication server, in a PCKE workflow?). It sounds logical enough in theory, but for the life of me I just can't find an understandable model for turning that theory into reality. I'm surprised I don't see more people having the same sort of confusion, so I wonder if I'm just missing something completely basic.
- The YouTube tutorial I linked above seemed pretty strong, right up until it started embedding the Client Secrets directly into the (React) app, which everyone (including the guy on the video) seems to agree is a huge no-no. I'm guessing those secrets belong instead in the code on the Authorization Server (well, rather, in the environment variables of the server), but, again, it's not clear to me if libraries like drf-social-oauth2 facilitate such a setup.
- Have I been right to focus so much on OAuth2, or should I have been learning more above OpenID Connect (OIDC)?

That's just the start of my confusion. Even once I figure out the above and get my API to successfully grant tokens to my mobile app, a whole new set of questions arise:

- Since I want my users to stay continuously logged in, what should my token management strategy be? Should I even bother with refresh tokens, or is there a use case for issuing access tokens with no expiration date?
- Is there a strong argument to be made for using JWTs instead?
- Is it (relatively) okay to store tokens in shared preferences on an Android app?
- If I do rely on refresh tokens, is there a general strategy for how long access and refresh tokens should each last? And how/when in the app workflow should tokens be refreshed? (NOTE: This is the question I've done the least research on so far. I mainly include it here to underscore how lost I've gotten in trying to figure all this out.)

And then the more existential questions:

- If I implement this all perfectly, how much am I actually accomplishing? Like, even with client secrets hidden away in an authorization server and PCKE in play and all that, someone who roots a phone and decompiles my code and can mimic user registration and get a token and make API requests, right?
- In other words, am I even asking the right questions?

Anyway, apologies for the lengthy confusion of this post. I think I'm probably 70% hoping for answers, 20% looking to vent, and 10% hoping for moral support. It'd be great if someone can maybe at least let me know if I'm on the right track; or point me that direction if I'm not. Thanks!